# Set cookie using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cookies

I have set a cookie while loading the page (not using AJAX) using PHP.

Later, I have an AJAX PHP script which does some work, attempts to delete the cookie by including `setcookie('my_cookie', '', time()-3600);`, returns `header('Content-Type: text/plain')` with some text, and then the browser reloads the page based on the response.

The cookie isn't deleted.  I then realize I am not sending HTML to the browser, but some text and/or JSON.  I read some other posts at SO, and it sounds like I should be able to do so.  I suppose I can delete the cookie using JavaScript, however, would rather not.

How should I best delete the cookie?  Thanks

Comment: if you are going to reload the page anyway why do it with ajax?

Comment: Setting a cookie to the past has nothing to do with PHP being hacky, it forces the browser (which is what's being hacky) to delete the cookie which is a file on the client computer. There is no way PHP could touch a client filesystem (when used in a browser, obviously it could do it if used outside of a web environment) use `unset($_COOKIE["my_cookie"]);`  instead

Comment: The server cookie handling should happen regardless of what the http request returns.

Comment: Be aware cookie names are case sensitive. Have you verified the cookie name is exactly the same?

Comment: 3600 = 1h is too few to set as expiry time. In real world, if someone is located at a time difference > 1h from your server, the cookie won't be expired on those clients. Try 24h, i.e. time() - 86400

Comment: @KevPrice.  To be consistent with all my other script.  This AJAX routine is to log off, so I wanted it to delete any sessions/cookies, and reload the page which will result in the log on page being displayed.  Yes, I can do it with  AJAX but it would be a one-off.

Comment: @NullPointer.  PHP might not directly touch the client file system, but it does create the headers which are sent to the client browser which create a file for the cookie.

Comment: @mplungjan.  I am not interested in effecting the cookie at the server, but effecting the cookie stored on the client.

Comment: @Al_.  Thanks, I did not know that.  Regardless, they are the same case.

Comment: Cookies are only ever stored on the client regardless of where they were instigated.

Comment: @Al_.  Good point.  I based it on http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php.  They probably need to add a word of warning.

Comment: @mplungjan.  Agree.  I mean just unsetting an element in the $_COOKIE array will not delete the cookie stored on the client.

Comment: I think I found part of the problem.  I enter the following into the browser, and find that different cookies are associated with each page.  I thought they would all be the same.  http://www.mysite.com/demo/index.php, http://www.mysite.com/demo/, http://mysite.com/demo/index.php